# Hiding a secret in Terraform for Azure with a caveat

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

So I am trying to find someway to hide a secret in Terraform.  The caveat is the secret is a Service Principal that is used to connect to our Key Vault.  I can't store the secret in the Key Vault as it hasn't connected to the Key Vault yet at that point.  This is part of my main tf file.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  alias           = "kv_prod"
  version         = "1.28"
  tenant_id       = "<tenant id>"
  subscription_id = "<sub id>"
  client_id       = "<SP client id>"
  client_secret   = "<SP secret>"
}
```

This is used further down my module to store Storage Account keys and other secrets.  It just happens to be in a Prod subscription that not everyone has access to.

Has anyone run into something like this?  If so, how would you go about securing that secret?

Comment: Are you running your Terraform scripts as part of continuous deployment?  If so, what tool/platform are you using, is it something like Azure DevOps.  Most continuous deployment tools will have some mechanism to store a secret like this securely and then inject it in as a variable when a deployment pipeline runs. So then the secret to the key value is used at runtime but you don't have it in your IaC source code or the Terraform state.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  We are not using any deployment tools.  TF is run manually by the dev who is consuming the module.  So developer pulls down the variable file so they can set their variables.  They they run their own plan and apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to create an ADO pipeline to handle this instead where the code just does not have to be available.

Answer (score 4):

@maltman There are several ways to hide a secret in terraform. Here is a blog that talks about them:

https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/configuration-management/secrets-management-with-terraform/

However if you are only concerned about encrypting the secrets file while checking in and checking out from git, you can use something like [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt#git-crypt---transparent-file-encryption-in-git)

You would have to create a couple of files:

variables.tf -> Define your variables here

```
variable "client_secret" {
  description = "Client Secret"
}
```

terraform.tfvars -> Give the value of the variable here

```
client_secret = 'your-secret-value'
```

Now use `git-crypt` to encrypt terraform.tfvars while checking into git

Comment: Yeah that is what I am looking into now.  So my users have their TF file that they store their variables in.  I guess this would be equivalent to the tfvars file.  I can't store the secret value there.  Should I just store it in code in the main module TF file?

Comment: tfvars file has the value of the variables present in the variables.tf file. You should use the variables in your main.tf file like this: `client_secret   = var.client_secret`. You should encrypt the tfvars file so that the secret is not visible to everyone on Git. Alternatively you can have the secret in the main code but that is not good practice. You can have multiple tfvars file as mentioned in the blog. One tfvars file can hold all the secrets.

Comment: Nice.  will give that a shot.

Comment: I am trying to figure out a way to do this that will not require anything else passed to the command line when running an apply.  I can't add anything to the process as it is already too difficult for some of my users (I know but what can you do).  I was thinking about just adding a separate file that does not have to be passed with the apply and maybe use that.  Still testing.

Answer (score 2):

For your requirements, I think there are two secure ways for you in comparison.

One is that stored the credential as environment variables so that you do not expose the secret in the tf files. Here's the [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/auth/service_principal_client_secret.html#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform).

The other one is that you can log in with the credential for Azure CLI, then just need to set the subscription without exposing the secret in the tf file. Here's the [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/auth/azure_cli.html).

The above two ways are that what I think is secure and possible for you. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you Charles.  I will try them both out.

Comment: @maltman Good luck to you, I'm still waiting for your good news.

Comment: So was just looking at both options.  Neither may work as I would need to configure something to set environment variables or use the CLI.  In my case, this would probably be powershell.  I can then store the script in a Storage Account but I would then to encrypt the SA Access Key which I would need to store in the Key Vault which I do not have access to yet because the value I am trying to protect is the Key Vault secret.

Comment: I think I need something that would encrypt the secret so it can not be seen when inserting to GitHub and when being checked out.

Comment: @maltman I don't think it's possible that encrypt the secret as I know. And you also cannot access the key vault before you connect to the Azure.

Comment: Not yet.  I was looking at a way to utilize the tfvars but, since we do not use ADO for TF deployments, I do not want to make the process more difficult.  And adding a parameter to the TF apply/plan will make it more difficult for my users.  Also looking at git-crypt but Windows support seems to be lacking.

Comment: @maltman I think the solutions that I had provided are the most available in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform doesn't have this feature but by using third party integration it can be achieved.

- Storing Secret in Terraform:

  Terraform has an `external` data resource that can be used to run an external program and use the return value further. I have used Ansible vault feature to encrypt and decrypt the secrets and store it encrypted in repository rather as plaintext.

  ```
  data "external" "mysecret" {
   program = ["bash", "-c", "${path.module}/get_ansible_secret.sh"]

   query = {      
       var                 = "${var.secret_value}"
       vault_password_file = "${path.module}/vault-password.sh"
       # The file containing the secret we want to decrypt
       file = "${var.encrypted_file}"
   }
  }
  ```

Refer the working example: [github example](https://github.com/mattyait/terraform_ansible_vault)

Comment: Thanks Mahattam.  We just purchased Terraform Enterprise so I think I will use that to pull the secret at runtime once we get it all set up.